# Recommend a good web-based querying system for MySql?

Tags: mysql

Can anyone recommend a good web-based querying system for MySql?  I'd like to be able to create various reports on the data in my db (I'm happy to concoct these in SQL), and then be able to view the results, perhaps adjusting parameters like start and end date.

Extra points if it is viewable on a smart-phone device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/).